# Using modules as namespaces to override built-in classes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, module

I have a `Date` class which I would like to use to overwrite Ruby's `Date` class. However, whenever I do a `require 'Date'` in my other files, it includes Ruby's `Date` class and not my own.

I thought that putting it in a module would work well, so I did so within the `Date.rb` file:

```
module myModule
  class Date
  #...
  end
end
```

However I still can't figure out how to make my other classes include THIS `Date` class and not the built-in class. How can I achieve this?

All help is appreciated and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adam,

Your best bet is to simply follow some conventions:

1. Always name your filenames lower case (`date.rb` not `Date.rb`)
2. Put your files in a specific directory inside your library (`lib` is a good candidate)
3. Don't name your files the same thing as built in Ruby classes (call it `my_date.rb` or something) or if your class/module is name-spaced inside a module, put it in a folder of the module name (`lib/my_module/date.rb`).

This removes any ambiguity in which file you are trying to load. If you absolutely must keep it named `date.rb`, then load it with the full path by doing something like: `File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "date.rb")`.

For debugging purposes you can look at the following special variables to see what's being loaded instead of your file:

- `$:` will show the load path (i.e. every directory it looks in to find files to require. You will note that the current directory (`.`) is last. This is why your file isn't loaded -- it looks in the system path first. You can always move your current directory to the front of the load path as a solution by doing `$:.unshift(File.dirname(__FILE__))`, but I'd try one of the above approaches before resorting to this
- `$"` shows every file that has been required into your current environment so far.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'path/to/Date.rb'

class MyClass
    include MyModule::Date
end
```

Comment: I should specify that `Date.rb` is the same directory as the class that I want to include it in.

Comment: then do `require "./Date.rb"`

Comment: @bjeanes: I tried this: `irb(main):003:0> require "./Date.rb"
=> false` How can I figure out why the include didn't work?

Comment: `require` returning false does not necessarily mean that it did not work. In any case, try doing `require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "Date.rb")` to be sure. Really, the simplest solution is to just call the file something else, like `my_custom_date.rb`. The class/module name does NOT have to match the file name.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to require the correct file. Often the right thing happens when you do `require 'date'` and it's resolved to a file based on your $LOAD_PATH. You can be more specific by putting your date.rb in a directory so you can `require 'my_module/date'` or just use a relative path like `./date`

You can then specify the module hierarchy when referring to this class:

```
::MyModule::Date
```

Or you can include it wherever you prefer to call this `Date` over the standard one without specifying:

```
class Event
  include MyModule
  def initialize
    @date = Date.today # refers to MyModule::Date
  end
end
```

Comment: `>require ::MyModule::Date` gets me `NameError: uninitialized constant MyModule::Date`

Comment: require is a filename string, not module name.

Comment: Right. So how do I require the correct file? And is there a way to make this so that I don't have to specify ::MyModule::Date, similar to Java's `import`?

Comment: Updated my answer for your questions.

Comment: This isn't working for me -- perhaps because my module is in a file that's not of the same name as the module? (`module MyModule` contains `class Date` and is in `Date.rb`)

Comment: Also, would it help if I put `Event` inside `MyModule` as well?

Comment: If you're on a case-sensitive filesystem, I guess there might be a difference between `require 'date'` and `require 'Date'`. This just refers to a filename, so it either has to be in your `$LOAD_PATH` or you have to specify the path to it. As for putting your Event class inside your module, sure, why not: then your Date class will be available there and you won't need to include it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't solve my problem -- I thought my filesystem was case-sensitive, but apparently not. Also, I want a fix that works on any filesystem, so this is just a hack that works on one filesystem or another.